# Crowdin: how to move translation entries from one file to another

Tags: move, crowdin

I created a translation entry "Roundabout.option:stay in lane" In the wrong file (menu.csv). Now I need to move the entry from to menu.csv to options.csv.
One way is to delete the entry from menu.csv and then create a new one in the options.csv but then I have to copy paste all the translations from multiple languages as well. This approach is tedious and may result in mistakes.

Is there any convenient way to move translation entries from one file to another?

Answer (score 0):

you can pre-translate your file with your project's TM, so the translations will be automatically added to the new string.